# How to search for a specific element in list

Tags: list, erlang

I want to retrieve id(which is 1 in this case) for the first appearing `"Apple"` in a list. For example:

```
List = [["1","Apple"],["2","Orange"],["3","Apple"]].
```

Comment: Is the format of your list pre-defined? If not, you may want to look at using tuples for the individual items and an integer for the id, e.g. [{1, "Apple"}, {2, "Orange"}, {3, "Apple"}, ...] which will allow you to use the proplists (http://erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html) functions.

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Click this comment to find out how to provide what we need to help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

In Erlang world, for fixed-size data types we use `tuple`s. Your List may grow up but i thinks its elements are fixed-size, So i recommend to use tuple for its elements and you can use API functions of modules [lists](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html) and [proplists](http://erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html):

```
1> List = [{"1", "Apple"}, {"2", "Orange"}, {"3", "Apple"}].
[{"1","Apple"},{"2","Orange"},{"3","Apple"}]
%% Search in List for a tuple which its 2nd element is "Apple":
2> lists:keyfind("Apple", 2, List).
{"1","Apple"}
3> lists:keyfind("Unknown", 2, List).
false
%% Take first Tuple which its 2nd element is "Apple", Also yield Rest of List:
4> lists:keytake("Apple", 2, List).
{value,{"1","Apple"},[{"2","Orange"},{"3","Apple"}]}
%% Replace a tuple which its 1st element is "3" with {"3", "Banana"}
5> lists:keyreplace("3", 1, List, {"3", "Banana"}).
[{"1","Apple"},{"2","Orange"},{"3","Banana"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple recursive function is probably what you're looking for here.

```
find_key([], _) -> error;
find_key([[Key, Value] | Rest], Search) when Value = Search -> Key;
find_key([_ | Rest], Search) -> find_key(Rest, Search).
```

Comment: I think in C implemented BIF `lists:keyfind/2` will be way better.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil For an actual system, I agree. I couldn't tell if they were writing this for themselves as an exercise, or if this was intended for real-world use. I answered with the exercise in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`lists:search/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#search-2) for that:

```
List = [["1","Apple"],["2","Orange"],["3","Apple"]],
{value, [Id, "Apple"]} =
  lists:search(fun([Id, Name]) -> Name == "Apple" end, List),
Id.
```